# how to generate n samples from a line segment using Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, line-segment

Given n samples of 100,how do we generate these random samples in the line segment below using  matlab

line_segement:

x between -1 and 1, y=2

Comment: Do you want generate n random sample (values) between -1 and 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate `n` random samples between to given limit (in your question `-1` and `1`), you can use the function `rand`.

Here an example:

```
% Define minimum x value
x_min=-1
% Define maximum x value
x_max=1
% Define the number of sample to be generated
n_sample=100
% Generate the samples
x_samples = sort(x_min + (x_max-x_min).*rand(n_sample,1))
```

In the example, the `sort` function is called to sort the values in order to have an `ascendent` series.

`x_min` and `(x_max-x_min)` are used to "shift" the series of random values so that it belongs to the desired interval (in this case `-1 1`), since `rand` returns random number on an open interval `(0,1)`.

If you want to have a XY matrix composed by the random samples and the defined constant y value (2):

```
y_val=2;
xy=[x_samples ones(length(x_samples),1)*y_val]

plot([x_min x_max],[y_val y_val],'linewidth',2)
hold on
plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'d','markerfacecolor','r')
grid on
legend({'xy segment','random samples'})
```

(in the picture, only 20 samples have been plot to make it more clear)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.This was very helpful